# How can I process Vue.js props before actually using them?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Imagine the following situation:

I have a `Menu` component with 2 props:

- `items`
- `filterTerm`

The `Menu` component can't just simply display the items.. It has to filter it first according to the given `filterTerm`.

This raises 2 questions:

1. I don't know where to process `items` before displaying them. I've researched the [Components documentation](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html) and they don't seem to mention any *life-cycle* methods.
2. Is it a good idea to *mutate* the received `items` prop? Unless Vue performs a deep clone on every render, which I find unreasonable, mutating a prop may have side-effects. Therefore, I shouldn't actually filter the received `items`. I should *clone*  it first, but then where would I do it?  I could do it in the `data:function() { }` but then my `methods` are not available there :(

So, what is the proper way of filtering the `items` before displaying them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that computed properties are good for that:

Let's imagine this data:

```
let raw = [
    {
        id: 1,
        link: '/some-link',
        name: 'some-name'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        link: '/other-link',
        name: 'other-name'
    }
]
```

And that component that takes this data in property:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in formated"><a :href="item.href">{{ item.libel }}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['raw'],
        computed: {
            formated () {
                let menu = []
                for(let i  0; i < this.raw.length; i++) {
                    menu.push({
                        libel: this.raw[i].name,
                        href: this.raw[i].link
                    })
                }
                return menu
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, the `formated` method is a computed property that will update each time your `raw` property change.